# Getting this error Error: Unknown property 'deleteRowsExample.Opportunity_Split__c'

Tags: visualforce

> Error: Unknown property 'deleteRowsExample.Opportunity_Split__c
>   *Quick Fix Create Apex property 'deleteRowsExample.Opportunity_Split__c'
>   *Quick Fix Create Apex method 'deleteRowsExample.getOpportunity_Split__c'

Please help me to remove this error since I am new to Salesforce

Class

```
public class deleteRowsExamples {

    public List<Opportunity_Split__c> allOpportunitySplit = new List<Opportunity_Split__c>();

    public List<Opportunity_Split__c> deleteOpportunitySplit = new List<Opportunity_Split__c>();

    public Opportunity OpportunityRec {get;set;}

    public void deleteRowsExamples(){
        ID aid = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id');
        OpportunityRec = [Select Id,Name from Opportunity where Id=:aid]; 
        allOpportunitySplit = [Select Id,Team_Member__c,Percent__c,Amount__c,Note__c from Opportunity_Split__c where Opportunity__c=:OpportunityRec.id];
    }

    public List<Opportunity_Split__c> getContacts(){
        return allOpportunitySplit;
    }

    public void addContact(){
        Opportunity_Split__c c = new Opportunity_Split__c();
        allOpportunitySplit.add(c);
    }

    public void removeContact(){
        Integer indexVal = Integer.valueof(system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('index'));

        if(allOpportunitySplit[indexVal - 1].Id != null)
            deleteOpportunitySplit.add(allOpportunitySplit[indexVal - 1]);

        allOpportunitySplit.remove(indexVal - 1);            
    }    
    public void saveChanges(){

        upsert allOpportunitySplit;

        if(deleteOpportunitySplit.size() > 0)
            delete deleteOpportunitySplit;
    }    

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="deleteRowsExamples" tabStyle="Opportunity">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock > 
    <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{!addContact}" immediate="true"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="{!saveChanges}"/>

<BR><h1>Revenue</h1></BR>
<BR><h1>Split on Opportunity-Amount</h1>Each split assignment for this split type must total 100%</BR> 



  <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Opportunity_Split__c }" var="con">
   <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cnt"/>
      <apex:column headervalue="Action">
          <apex:commandlink value="Remove" action="{!removeContact}" immediate="true">

              <apex:param name="index" value="{!cnt}"/>
          </apex:commandlink> 
          <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>              
      </apex:column>  
      <apex:column headerValue="Team Member">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!con.Team_Member__c}"/>
      </apex:column> 
      <apex:column headerValue="Percent(%)">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!con.Percent__c}"/>
      </apex:column>  
      <apex:column headerValue="Amount">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!con.Amount__c}"/>
      </apex:column> 
      <apex:column headerValue="Note">
          <apex:inputfield value="{!con.Note__c}"/>
      </apex:column>          
  </apex:pageblocktable>

</apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your code... it needed a decent amount of cleaning up :)

Controller:

```
public class deleteRowsExamples {
    // Define Map and List
    public Map<Id, Opportunity_Split__c> oppSplits      { get; set; }
    public List<Opportunity_Split__c> oppSplitsToDelete { get; set; }

    // Define Opportunity sObject record
    public Opportunity opp { get; set; }

    // Define Opp Id
    public Id oppId { get; set; }

    // Define visualforce page param of record to be deleted
    public String recIdToDelete { get; set; }

    // Main method that is automatically called and complies before the page loads
    public deleteRowsExamples(){
        // Get record Id from URL param "id" set it to oppId, it makes a little
        // more sense than using aid which I assumed was Account Id at first
        oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        // Get Opp details
        getOpp();

        // Get Releated Splits
        getSplits();
    }

    public void getOpp(){
        // You may want to add some error handling here just in case
        // the Opportunity Id has not been set in the URL
        opp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: oppId];
    }

    public void getSplits(){
        // You will want this query only to run if there is an opp
        if(opp != null && opp.size() > 0){
            oppSplits = [Select Id, Team_Member__c, Percent__c, Amount__c, Note__c
                         FROM Opportunity_Split__c
                         WHERE Opportunity__c =: opp.id];
        }
    }

    public void addSplit(){
        // Instantiate a new Opp Split
        Opportunity_Split__c os = new Opportunity_Split__c();

        // Add the new Opp Split to the oppSplits Map
        oppSplits.add(os);
    }

    public void removeSplit(){
        // Remove the Opp Split to be deleted from the oppSplits Map
        oppSplits.remove(recIdToDelete);

        // If you want to remove the split instantly, you should use the
        // following and delete everything after this in this method, then remove
        // delete from the saveChanges() method
        // delete oppSplitsToDelete;

        // Add the Opp Split to the oppSplitsToDelete List
        oppSplitsToDelete.add(recIdToDelete);
    }

    public void saveChanges(){
        // Upsert the values of oppSplits Map
        upsert oppSplits.values();

        // If there are Opp Splits to delete then delete
        if(oppSplitsToDelete.size() > 0)
            delete oppSplitsToDelete;
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="deleteRowsExamples" tabStyle="Opportunity">
    <apex:form id="all">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Revenue Split on Opportunity-Amount"> 
            Each split assignment for this split type must total 100%
            <!--
Use the apex:pageBlockButtons to display buttons within the current apex:pageBlock it's a little
cleaner and you can define if you want them at the top or bottom, or leave location out entirely
to have them in both places
-->
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <!--
If you want the page to reload all the content you need to add reRender="all"
to your command buttons to reference the apex:form content and reload it
-->
                <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{! addSplit }" immediate="true"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="{! saveChanges }" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageblocktable value="{! oppSplits }" var="os">
                <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                    <!--
Instead of using a link you can use a commanButton and an apex Param with
the id of the record to be deleted, this is referenced in the controller and
removed from the Map to be deleted, if you want deletions to happen instantly
you will need to update your controller to do so
-->
                    <apex:commandbutton value="Remove" action="{! removeSplit }">
                        <apex:param assignTo="{! recIdToDelete }" name="recIdToDelete" value="{! os.Id }" />
                    </apex:commandbutton>
                </apex:column>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Team Member">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{! os.Team_Member__c  }"/>
                </apex:column> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Percent(%)">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{! os.Percent__c }"/>
                </apex:column>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Amount">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!os.Amount__c}"/>
                </apex:column> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Note">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!os.Note__c}"/>
                </apex:column>          
            </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if anything doesn't work... I was unable to test it as I do not have an Object called Opportunity Splits :)

Couple of tips, these are my personal opinions, so someone else might disagree...

1. Your use of removeContact, you should always use something that is as descriptive as possible, but not toooooo long...

   - On your VF page "Remove Contact" might be what the business needs to see, however as you are actually removing an Opportunity Split, I would recommend using `removeSplit` instead as it makes a little more sense and it will be easier to understand for the next dev to have a look at
2. public List allOpportunitySplit = new List();

   - I would personally never define a List and instantiate it instantly... I always instantiate it inside a method where the List is being used or may be used, this is for silly things like load time, which won't make a difference if you have a small org, but I have worked on some big one's and it does matter :)
3. Use of Map<>

   - You were using apex:variable to be able to remove the relevant record, however if you used Map<> as I did and just reference the Id in the apex:param of the button you instantly have an Id that you can use to remove a record from a Map<> and create new records etc... if you wanted you can convert that button back to a apex:commandlink, I just personally prefer buttons :)

Comment: wow, i really didn't know these things, thank you sooo much for your Valuable efforts. i'll try to add up these things in my code from next time.

Comment: That's no problem :) there's always room to learn more! I do pretty much daily at my work :)

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM I would recommend reading http://advancedapex.com/ it's an incredible book! You will learn a LOT from it... I did and still am (only half way through)

Comment: yaa for sure,,,,,,,,,,,,, i'll try to complete it asap,,,,,,,,,, can i get connected with u on linkedin if u don't mind,,,, :)

Comment: of course you can :) https://uk.linkedin.com/in/gentet

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM could you mark my answer as being the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `public void onloadMethod()` to `public deleteRowsExample()`

You may want to have a read of the SF documentation... this is something very basic you should learn about if you are going into development :)

Try readin up here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm

Comment: Timothy i have tried this before to make this method as constructor but it's not working with that that's why i changed it's method name and called it explicitely. still its giving the same error

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM Okay, can you actually paste your code instead of a screenshot... I can have a look into it a little more if you like? It will probably be something basic that you are overlooking :)

Comment: i have pasted the controller & apex code

Comment: please check it @Timothy

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM give me 5 I am going to clean this up and comment a little for you :)

Comment: hey Timothy, i have got why the error was coming, actually i was not using the value of pageblock table as {!Contacts} since i m having getContacts method so i changed the value of pageblocktable as {!contacts} now my code is running without error. thanks you so much for your efforts. @Timothy